# FindWindowW for devexpress dialog Windows

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm using Vb.net and Devexpress Controls.
I have a situation where I need to detect if a messagebox is shown on my application.
I'm using this function :

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindowW")> _
Private Function FindWindowW(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpClassName As String,      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Function IsMessageBox() As Boolean
    Return (FindWindowW("#32770", "Warning !") <> IntPtr.Zero)
End Function
```

If I use the Microsoft standart MessageBox , everything is working .
If I use the devexpress's XtraMessageBox , the function IsMessageBox always return false.
Is there any other class number for Devexpress dialog Windows ? ( different than #32770 )

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

All the DevExpress forms, like any other managed forms, gets a window class name like  `"WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.bf7d44"`. It changes every time you build the application.

The standard .NET `MessageBox` class is a P/Invoke wrapper around the Win32 `MessageBox` function. As such, it has a window class name of `"#32770"`, corresponding to the [global class for a dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574.aspx).

You can check whether the DevExpress XtraMessageBox is shown or not using the following trick:

[C#]

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class MessageBoxHelper {
    public static bool IsXtraMessageBoxShown {
        get { return Application.OpenForms.OfType<DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBoxForm>().Any(); }
    }
}
```

[VB.NET]

```vb
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Windows.Forms

NotInheritable Class MessageBoxHelper
   Public Shared ReadOnly Property IsXtraMessageBoxShown() As Boolean
      Get
         Return Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBoxForm)().Any()
      End Get
   End Property
End Class
```